# vue-cli app hosted in IIS. Caching problems

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, iis

I've not been able to find straight forward instructions on how to avoid caching problems when developing a js app with vue cli.

For example, when we deploy a new version of the app with npm run build, we can see that a new app.xxxxx.js is deployed, where the xxxxxx part is a new hash that I guess webpack is generating.

We host this in an Windows 2012 IIS Server.

Now when I tell my customer we have solved the latest issues that have been found in the app, it seems that they have caching problems, as they still have the previous version, even if they close and reopen the browser.

Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the below steps which help you to disable the cache in iis.

1)Open iis manager.

2)Select the site and click on the "HTTP response header feature".

3)Click on the set common header link from the action pane.

4)click the checkbox "expire web content" and select "immediately" radio button.

[image]

You could also set output caching in iis:

[Configure IIS Output Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching)